# How to pass multiple images in WCF REST service using postman

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

Here I can select only one image at a time.But I want to select multiple images.Somebody please help me. If I am selectingmultiple images also it is saving only one image.I am selecting images using postman service.

```
public ServiceResponse<string> UploadDoc(Stream fileContents)
            {

                IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;


                string fileName = woc.Headers["fileName"];
                if (fileName.Length <= 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("File not attached");
                }


                if (fileName == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Please send fileName in header");
                }

                //string userId = woc.Headers["UserAuthor"];

                string fileNameUnique = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
                string upload_FilePath = @"" + docFolder + "\\" + fileNameUnique;
                string fileUrl = hostUrl + "/Document/" + fileNameUnique;
                try
                {

                    int length = 0;

                    using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(upload_FilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        int readCount;
                        var buffer = new byte[8192];

                        while ((readCount = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                            length += readCount;
                        }
                    }

                    var response = new ServiceResponse<string>
                    {
                        ResponseObject = fileUrl
                    };

                    return response;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var response = new ServiceResponse<string>
                    {
                        IsError = true,
                        ExceptionObject = new ExceptionModel()
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = e.Message,
                            Source = e.Source,
                            Severity = 0,
                            KeyParameter = new[] { "ServiceError" }
                        }
                    };
                    return response;
                }

            }
```

Comment: The name of your service operation is *public ServiceResponse<string> UploadDoc(Stream fileContents)*. This would appear to only allow a single document.

Comment: I am not able to save single object also,If I am saving single object I am getting image with error.Can you say  how I can?

Comment: Though we are powerful, StackOverflow has not yet evolved the ability to read your mind. Your question is unanswerable. If you're getting an error then you have to tell us what the error is. Otherwise, how are we supposed to help? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you can try changing your Stream parameter to a class like this.

```
public class FilesRequest
{
     public ICollection<Stream> MyStreams { get; set; }
}

public ServiceResponse<string> UploadDoc(FilesRequest request)
{
   // Process the collection in your input, request.MyStreams
}
```